# Getting Loads of Emails 'linking' my account to Gmail accounts I know nothing about

Tags: email

I have just come out of hospital and have in the region of 30 e-mails from gmail over the past few days 'linking' a gmail account to my (hotmail) email address.  I have not done this once never mind 30 times!

the supposed gmail accounts are made up of random letters and numbers eg vvcxzzx.comvcxzdfgh.com@gmail.com

How do I stop this?  Surely someone like google should not be allowing this to happen?

Thanks in advance for any advice :)

Comment: Have you looked at Google's help page for suspected gmail abuse? https://support.google.com/mail/topic/3394218?hl=en&rd=2

Answer (score 1):

You can create a random gmail address and then link it to an existing email address for password recovery. You can fill in any address there I believe, and you don't have to be logged into that address, which is not relevant anyway if it's not a gmail address.

So I don't know how you can stop this, but you can contact Google and ask them if they can stop it.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment of Graham Hill suggested, check the webpage, and of course, change your password immediately! This is of utmost importance with any type of abuse with mail accounts.

Comment: I didn't get the need to changing password. Can you help me understand this?

Comment: @PavanW3b because of the possibility that the account has been compromised, even so, in ANY "shady" situation including accounts, after you solved it, it's always the best move to firstly scan your PC for malware (keyloggers, eh?), and as second change the password on your Mail Account, it's the same procedure when an mail account has been "hacked" and is used to send spam mails to your contacts.